# Syntax error near unexpected token - shell scripting

Tags: shell, syntax, scripting

I am new to shell scripting and I am trying to write a simple script to run a number of files through a program. I am trying to take a file, all of which begin with the name `restart` and are located in the `r0970.t240` directory, and copy an individual file to the file `st2.res` which is the name of the file the program I am running takes in and analyzes and is located in a directory called `crystal`. This is the process I wish to repeat for all the files. I have made an attempt at doing so, but when I attempt to run the script I get the following error message:

```
 line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `cp'.
```

I know there's a lot of specificity when it comes to shell scripts in terms of spaces and symbols and what not, so I am most likely overlooking something but due to my inexperience I don't know quite what. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the script in question:

```
cd ~Documents/work/useful/r0970.t240
for file in restart*
cp $file ~/desktop/crystal/st2.res
cd ~/desktop/crystal
./a.out
rm st2.res
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (`for`) loop in shell scripting requires a `do` as part of its head. You should also quote your variables, especially when dealing with filenames, otherwise your scripts will break on filenames with spaces.

E.g.:

```
for file in restart*; do
#                   ^^^^
    cp "$file" ~/desktop/crystal/st2.res
    [...]
done
```

You should also consider, rather than `cd`ing into a directory, to use absolute paths and to indent your code for better readability.

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed my problem perfectly. I will keep these tips in mind as I continue looking into shell scripting.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Still getting to know the site :-P